# Changing CSS based on input checked

Tags: css

Apologies in advance because I know this is a silly question.  I am using the following CSS code to change the background color of a label when it's associated checkbox is checked:

```
#project input[id="button1"]:checked + label {background-color:red;}
```

I want to ALSO change the background color of the entire page when `id="button1"` is checked.  Is that possible? I tried adding to the line and a new line with no success:

```
input[id="button1"]:checked {background-color:blue;}
```

Shouldn't that affect the background outside the `DIV`?  I can't figure it out.  The finished product should have both the label background color and the page background color connected to the state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Via pure CSS events you can only change styles of the elements that are **children** of the element that toggled the event. Your body is never a children of the `checkbox` `input` (unless you are high). So the only option is some JavaScript/jQuery.

[Basic simple example](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/OPYRLB)

```
var button = document.getElementById('button1');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('blue');
});
```

Comment: Very nice!  Do you think this could be done without jQuery?  Maybe just inline javascript?  Or no?  (also thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

```
input[id="button1"]:checked {background-color:blue;}
```

"Shouldn't that affect the background outside the DIV?" - no, it will affect only that input element.

In general you cannot do that by only CSS means as you will need hypothetical :contains selector:

```
body:contains(input[id="button1"]:checked) {background-color:blue;}
```

Unfortunately that :contains has very high computational complexity to be implemented in CSS in general.